# Is there a way to define a general notion of density?

Tags: general-topology

I was asking my self if, given a topological space $X$, we can take a subset $A\subset X$ and say it's *dense*.
NEITHER "dense in $X$", NOR "dense somewhere else". Simply "dense".

Does a such a notion already exist?
I'd naturally define it -in a certain way- as the opposite of a *nowhere dense set*: I'd say $A$ is *dense* if its interior is $\neq\emptyset$.
It sounds good to me but if someone shade a light on this I would be really grateful! Many thanks

Comment: For you, is $\mathbb{R}$ dense?

Comment: WRT the usual topology $\Bbb R$ is first of all open in $\Bbb R$ hence it coincides with its interior, which thus is nonempty. So yes, I'd say that $\Bbb R$ is dense.

Comment: But if you're looking for a notion of density independant of the space X, why take the density of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and not in $\mathbb{C}$? Indeed, $\mathbb{R}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @Joe $\Bbb R$ is open in any topology on $\Bbb R$!

Comment: By your definition, every space is dense when considered by itself.

Comment: Thank! My definition was only an idea! I was asking you if there was a general definition of density

Comment: "Being dense" in the sense you mean it is a relation, so you're always dense *in* somebody. There's a way to make this precise (the notion of *dense monoorphism*), but it's rather difficult to give you the nitty-gritty.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you really want is a measure of "how much stuff" a set has, since this doesn't depend on the ambient space. In that case, you'd be talking about [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality). Granted, cardinal is so general that most other structures fall apart. In particular, it isn't a topological characteristic (indeed, $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb N$ have the same cardinal, but are not homeomorphic).